Trouble loading dataset on Kaggle -- OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
I've been trying to load a dataset that consists of a 1.46 GB .tgz file. This file contains ~2 million .pt files that I'm trying to use to train a neural network. I've been trying to load this dataset (called pt_files.tgz) on Kaggle using the following code:
import tarfile

# Specify the path to your .tgz file
tgz_file_path = '/kaggle/input/grb-dataset/pt_files.tgz'

# Directory to extract files into
output_folder = '/kaggle/working/pt_files'

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)


# Open the .tgz file and extract its contents
with tarfile.open(tgz_file_path, 'r:gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall(path=output_folder)

# Count the number of extracted files
num_files = len([name for name in os.listdir(output_folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(output_folder, name))])

print(f"Files extracted to {output_folder}")
print(f"Number of files extracted: {num_files}")


However, after a long time (probably ~20 mins), I get the following error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 16
     14 # Open the .tgz file and extract its contents
     15 with tarfile.open(tgz_file_path, 'r:gz') as tar:
---> 16     tar.extractall(path=output_folder)
     18 # Count the number of extracted files
     19 num_files = len([name for name in os.listdir(output_folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(output_folder, name))])

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py:2264, in TarFile.extractall(self, path, members, numeric_owner, filter)
   2259     if tarinfo.isdir():
   2260         # For directories, delay setting attributes until later,
   2261         # since permissions can interfere with extraction and
   2262         # extracting contents can reset mtime.
   2263         directories.append(tarinfo)
-> 2264     self._extract_one(tarinfo, path, set_attrs=not tarinfo.isdir(),
   2265                       numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
   2267 # Reverse sort directories.
   2268 directories.sort(key=lambda a: a.name, reverse=True)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py:2331, in TarFile._extract_one(self, tarinfo, path, set_attrs, numeric_owner)
   2327     self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name),
   2328                          set_attrs=set_attrs,
   2329                          numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
   2330 except OSError as e:
-> 2331     self._handle_fatal_error(e)
   2332 except ExtractError as e:
   2333     self._handle_nonfatal_error(e)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py:2327, in TarFile._extract_one(self, tarinfo, path, set_attrs, numeric_owner)
   2324 self._check("r")
   2326 try:
-> 2327     self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name),
   2328                          set_attrs=set_attrs,
   2329                          numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
   2330 except OSError as e:
   2331     self._handle_fatal_error(e)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py:2410, in TarFile._extract_member(self, tarinfo, targetpath, set_attrs, numeric_owner)
   2407     self._dbg(1, tarinfo.name)
   2409 if tarinfo.isreg():
-> 2410     self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
   2411 elif tarinfo.isdir():
   2412     self.makedir(tarinfo, targetpath)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py:2455, in TarFile.makefile(self, tarinfo, targetpath)
   2453 source.seek(tarinfo.offset_data)
   2454 bufsize = self.copybufsize
-> 2455 with bltn_open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
   2456     if tarinfo.sparse is not None:
   2457         for offset, size in tarinfo.sparse:

OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/kaggle/working/pt_files/pt_files/grb3.2e+48_3.2e-02_1.0e-02_3.2e-05_1.3e+06.pt'


I am fairly new to Kaggle, but I thought I was allowed to store up to 20 GB of data in my working directory. I checked how much data I was using in this directory (after I got the error message above) and this is what I got when I typed !df -h "/kaggle/working/":
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop1       20G  5.2G   15G  27% /kaggle/working


Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Would it be more convenient to upload my dataset to another cloud storage platform (e.g., Microsoft OneDrive) and then retrieve the data from Kaggle?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT: The size of the folder from which I created the compressed .tgz file is ~15 GB, so there shouldn't be any issues with the decompressed file exceeding my storage limit.
